# Laravel REST API cannot read input data from React Fetch Request

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, rest

I am building a simple web app with ReactJS frontend and Laravel backend using REST API. 
Here are my codes.

**Laravel Backend API for authentication**

```php
class UserController extends Controller 
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request) 
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        error_log(print_r($credentials, TRUE));

        try {
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        return  response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}
```

**ReactJS Frontend**

```js
login() {
    fetch ('http://localhost:8000/api/login',
        {
            header: {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password}),
        }
    )
    .then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

And the problem is, if you send the fetch request in react, the php terminal shows nothing but an empty array and receive:

> 400 Bad Request with invalid_credentials response

while Postman request is showing exactly what I gonna see.

What's the problem? Is my backend wrong?

Comment: your code enters in the if statement. It means the attempt call returns false. Check if the credentials you put are right

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `Content-Type` header.
Instead of fetch api can you axios?

Try this for fetch Api

```
login() {
    fetch ('http://localhost:8000/api/login',
        {
            header: {
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: ({email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password}),
        }
    )
    .then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

and for axios (this is working for me)

```
login() {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login',
    {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    })
    .then(res => {
     console.log(res.data)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is caused by CORS not allowed by the Laravel server. You should use laravel-cors package to disable it for desired routes.